# Hadoop/Mapreduce Reducer is not working

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, k-means

I got download about K-MEANS algorithm(in hadoop) from GitHub..
However, this only works in the maper.
(Because the output file name is "part-m-00000")
I hope the reduce output file.

my HDFS ordered: ./bin/hadoop jar Kmeans.jar Main input output

plz.. some body help me!!!!

here is Main.class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class Main{
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */

    static enum Counter{
        CONVERGED
    }

    public static final String CENTROIDS = "centroids";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {

        int iteration = 1;
        long changes = 0;
        Path dataPath = new Path(args[0]);

        //read in the initial cluster centroids.
        Configuration centroidConf = new Configuration();
        Job centroidInputJob = new Job(centroidConf);
        centroidInputJob.setJobName("KMeans Centroid Input");
        centroidInputJob.setJarByClass(Main.class);

        Path centroidsPath = new Path("centroids_0");

        centroidInputJob.setMapperClass(KmeansCentroidInputMapper.class);

        // No Combiner, no Reducer.

        centroidInputJob.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        centroidInputJob.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        centroidInputJob.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        centroidInputJob.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(centroidInputJob,new Path(args[1]) );
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(centroidInputJob, centroidsPath);
        centroidInputJob.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        if (!centroidInputJob.waitForCompletion(true)) {
            System.err.println("Centroid input job failed!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        while(true){
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            Path nextIter = new Path(String.format("centroids_%s", iteration));
            Path prevIter = new Path(String.format("centroids_%s", iteration - 1));
            conf.set(Main.CENTROIDS, prevIter.toString());

            Job job = new Job(conf);
            job.setJobName("Kmeans " + iteration);
            job.setJarByClass(Main.class);

            job.setJobName("KMeans "+ iteration);


            //Set Mapper, Combiner, and Reducer
            job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
            job.setReducerClass(ReduceClass.class);
            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
            job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
            job.setCombinerClass(CombineClass.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

            //Set input/output paths
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, dataPath);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, nextIter);

            job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
            job.waitForCompletion(true);
            iteration++;
            changes = job.getCounters().findCounter(Main.Counter.CONVERGED).getValue();
            job.getCounters().findCounter(Main.Counter.CONVERGED).setValue(0);
            if(changes<=0){
                break;
            }       
        }   
    }

}
```

Source code : https://github.com/yezhang1989/K-Means-Clustering-on-MapReduce

Comment: In your main class you have set number of reduce task to zero.That is why no reduce tsk is getting executed on your job.

Answer (score 1):

Please Command

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
```

And check if it is working.

Default Reducer for a MapReduce Job is 1 So need not set it as 1

job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
Reducer tasks wont run and output file depends on no of map(`part-m-00000`).